# bc truncate floating point number

Tags: linux, bash, bc

How do I truncate a floating point number using `bc`

e.g if I do

```
echo '4.2-1.3' | bc
```

which outputs `2.9` how I get it to truncate/use floor to get `2`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `/` operator.

```
echo '(4.2-1.3) / 1' | bc
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to always work: `echo '(l(101)/l(10)) / 1' | bc -l` returns a float.

Comment: it would still work if you do `echo 'scale=0; (l(101)/l(10)) / 1' | bc -l`

Comment: @JohnnyEverson that's because you're passing bc the `-l` flag which loads the math library and sets `scale` to 20. Otherwise, by default the scale is zero.

Answer (score 19):

Dividing by 1 works ok if `scale` is 0 (eg, if you start bc with `bc` and don't change `scale`) but fails if `scale` is positive (eg, if you start bc with `bc -l` or increase `scale`).  (See transcript below.)   For a general solution, use a `trunc` function like the following:
`define trunc(x) { auto s; s=scale; scale=0; x=x/1; scale=s; return x }`

Transcript that illustrates how divide by 1 by itself fails in the `bc -l` case, but how `trunc` function works ok at truncating toward zero:

```
> bc -l
bc 1.06.95
[etc...]
for (x=-4; x<4; x+=l(2)) { print x,"\t",x/1,"\n"}
-4  -4.00000000000000000000
-3.30685281944005469059 -3.30685281944005469059
-2.61370563888010938118 -2.61370563888010938118
-1.92055845832016407177 -1.92055845832016407177
-1.22741127776021876236 -1.22741127776021876236
-.53426409720027345295  -.53426409720027345295
.15888308335967185646   .15888308335967185646
.85203026391961716587   .85203026391961716587
1.54517744447956247528  1.54517744447956247528
2.23832462503950778469  2.23832462503950778469
2.93147180559945309410  2.93147180559945309410
3.62461898615939840351  3.62461898615939840351
define trunc(x) { auto s; s=scale; scale=0; x=x/1; scale=s; return x }
for (x=-4; x<4; x+=l(2)) { print x,"\t",trunc(x),"\n"}
-4  -4
-3.30685281944005469059 -3
-2.61370563888010938118 -2
-1.92055845832016407177 -1
-1.22741127776021876236 -1
-.53426409720027345295  0
.15888308335967185646   0
.85203026391961716587   0
1.54517744447956247528  1
2.23832462503950778469  2
2.93147180559945309410  2
3.62461898615939840351  3
```

Comment: one liner ex.: `bc <<< "scale=10;f=(3/55);scale=0;(312*f)/1"`

Answer (score 10):

Try the following solution. It will truncate anything after the decimal point without a problem:

```
echo 'x = 4.2 - 1.3; scale = 0; x / 1' | bc -l
echo 'x = l(101) / l(10); scale = 0; x / 1' | bc -l
```

You can make the code a tad shorter by performing calculations directly on the numbers:

```
echo 'scale = 0; (4.2 - 1.3) / 1' | bc -l
echo 'scale = 0; (l(101) / l(10)) / 1' | bc -l
```

In general, you can use this function to get only the integer part of a number:

```
define int(x) {
    auto s;
    s = scale;
    scale = 0;
    x /= 1; /* This will have the effect of truncating x to its integer value */
    scale = s;
    return (x);
}
```

Save that code into a file (let's call it *int.bc*) and run the following command:

```
echo 'int(4.2 - 1.3);' | bc -l int.bc
```

Answer (score 5):

The variable governing the amount of decimals **on division** is **scale**.

So, if scale is `0` (the default), dividing by 1 would truncate to `0` decimals:

```
$ echo '(4.2-1.3) / 1 ' | bc
2
```

In other operations, the number of decimals is calculated from the scale (number of decimals) of each operand. In add, subtract and multiplication, for example, the resulting scale is the biggest of both:

```
$ echo ' 4.2 - 1.33333333 ' | bc
2.86666667

$ echo ' 4.2 - 1.333333333333333333 ' | bc
2.866666666666666667

$ echo ' 4.2000 * 1.33 ' | bc
5.5860
```

Instead, in division, the number of decimals is strictly equal to th evalue of the variable `scale`:

```
$ echo 'scale=0;4/3;scale=3;4/3;scale=10;4/3' | bc
1
1.333
1.3333333333
```

As the value of scale has to be restored, it is better to define a function (GNU syntax):

```
$ echo ' define int(x){ os=scale;scale=0;x=x/1;scale=os;return(x) } 
         int( 4.2-1.3 )' | bc
2
```

Or in older POSIX language:

```
$ echo ' define i(x){
             o=scale;scale=0;x=x/1;scale=o;return(x)
         } 
         i( 4.2-1.3 )' | bc
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> truncate/use floor

And those are not the same thing in all cases. The other answers so far only show you how to truncate (i.e. "truncate towards zero" i.e. "discard the part after the decimal").

For negative numbers, the behavior is different.

To wit:

```
truncate(-2.5) = -2
floor(-2.5) = -3
```

So, here is a `floor` function for `bc`:

```
# Note: trunc(x) is defined as noted elsewhere in the other answers

define floor(x) {
    auto t
    t=trunc(x)
    if (t>x) {
        return t-1
    } else {
        return t 
    } 
}
```

Aside:

You can put this, and other helper functions, in a file. For instance, I have this alias in my shell:

```
alias bc='bc -l ~/.bcinit'
```

And so whenever I run `bc`, I get all my utility functions from `~/.bcinit` available by default.

Also, there is a good list of `bc` functions here: http://phodd.net/gnu-bc/code/funcs.bc

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this:

```
$ printf "%.2f\n" $(echo "(4530 / 4116 - 1) * 100" | bc -l)
10.06
```

Here I am trying to find the % change. Not purely bc though.